# Getting response headers

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Is it possible to get response headers from Chrome's Custom Tabs?
If yes, how?

Or if its possible with WebView, I want to get response cookies and I don't want to use networking libs like retrofit or okhttp

Comment: Do you control the page being opened inside the Custom Tab?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Tabs doesn't allow the host Android application to access response headers including Cookies.